# Angularjs - get previous states of a object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I'm constructing a component where I have multiple inputs of select type, they have options that are required. When a required field is used, it's deleted from the array of the requiredFields and added to the requiredFieldsRemoved array. If I change my mind and opted for another option of the select and i choose a field that is not required i must return the deleted object pushed into the requiredFieldsRemoved and returned to it's original requiredFields array.

What I did is add ng-change the input select which returns the object that changed, so what i need now is to save the previous states about the different changes that  the select can have.

```
//@Param publicationObject: change object from UI
$scope.itemValue = function (publicationObject) {

    // get the index using lodash
    var idx = lodash.findKey($scope.requiredFields, {
        name: publicationObject.name
    });

    // here I have to check whether the object already suffered
    // changes above or if it's his first change.
    // if it have change previously, i will check if that status match
    // to any object of the requiredFieldsRemoved array
    // and push it again to the requiredFields array, if not i just do nothing.
    //

    //if index is found, delete the item from required fields array
    if( idx !== undefined ) {
        $scope.requiredFields.splice(idx, 1);
        //add removed item to the requiredFieldsRemoved array
        requiredFieldsRemoved.push(publicationObject);

    }
};
```

What i can implement for getting those previous statuses?

Comment: $scope.itemValue = function (publicationObject) {
  var oldValue =  angular.copy(publicationObject)
};

Comment: try using angular.copy to store the old value before editing

Answer (score 0):

try using angular.copy

```
$scope.itemValue = function (publicationObject) {
    var oldValue = angular.copy(publica‌​tionObject) 
    //code
    };
```